# Comparing text type date and select the greater than dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sqldatatypes, date-arithmetic

I have a table with column(last_update_date) of data type is text.So I need to pass a date and select the greater than dates from the table.

I tried with below query,

```
select batch_uuid,result 
from @this 
where extract_status = 'success' 
  and last_update_date > '02/21/2019'
```

But above query is not working.
Any advice please.

Comment: `@this` is invalid SQL to begin with. But why on earth are you storing DATE values in a `varchar` column? That is really, really bad idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sometimes one does not have control over the databases that we use.

Comment: no this is already created table.I don't know who created this.I'm working on beanshell scripting platform. In there that's how they are writing PostgreSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's something I have to agree with. But some really bad software has been made and will be made in the future. Sometimes you have to adept despite knowing it's the wrong approach often because the cost to change everything are too big.

Comment: @MarkBaijens: I have the hope that the more we complain about this stupidity the less it happens (recently I stumbled over this related post: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/on-the-choice-of-datatypes/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Creating awareness is a good thing I think. However "But why on earth are you storing DATE values in a varchar" sound a lot different then for example "Do you have the possibility to change the datatype to date since using varchars for dates is a really bad idea." But i'm going offtopic now. I'll let this rest.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert both strings to dates to compare them:

```
select batch_uuid,result 
from mytable
where 
    extract_status = 'success' 
    and to_date(last_update_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') > to_date('02/21/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Note:

- `@this` is not a valid table, I changed it to `mytable`
- do consider storing dates in a date-like datatype; using a string datatype *will* bite you in many ways (to start with, using  a function like `to_date()` defeats an existing index on the column)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.